# In Unity3d I am having problems with a realistic simulation of a falling body

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a unity model with an animator attached that triggers idle to walk state.
The model is on a high ledge of a unity generated terrain.
I would like the model to fall off the ledge in a realistic way, i.e. bounce a bit/rotate coming to rest at the bottom.

If I add a character controller to the model it falls down but stays upright, not what I wanted here.

I tried using an empty game object that I added a rigid body and collider to and then added the model (without these things) as a child of the empty object.

I thought this had cracked it because the model rotated after leaving the ledge, bouced a bit on the way down but when landing at the base of the cliff went a bit mental rather than stopping at the bottom. Have run it a number of times and the model always continues to bounce around randomnly as though it is made of some weird magical rubber, sometimes it shoots off in the air again.

Where I want to go with this is that I have a first person shooter at the bottom of the cliff with a crossbow. The idea was that he shoots this guy at the top that then falls realistically to the bottom like a real person would.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: Google _rag-doll physics_.  Good luck!